# ON DUPLICATE KEY MYSQL Not Work

Tags: mysql

I have read for dozens thread but I dunno I could not figure it. I hope this thread won't duplicate.

So, I tried to insert data but in the end if the data has been on the table. It would update the value if it is not, then the data would be inserted into the table. I have read that I have to use

> INSERT INTO table() VALUES() ON DUPLICATE KEY data1='$data1', data2='$data2'

Then, here is my code

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO niche_new(gamename,domain,url,type,date) VALUES('$gamename','$websiteurl','$url','download','$waktu') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE domain='$websiteurl',url='$url'";
$process = $conn->query($sql) or die("Error: ".$conn->error);
```

> In the end of the query.
>
> The data won't be updated, but it is inserted. It makes my table has
>   lots of duplicate data.

I really appreciate any answers. Thank you :)

> Note: It was a great mistake. I forgot to set unique key on my table.
>   To whom who want to use ON DUPLICATE KEY, make sure you set UNIQUE KEY
>   by picking which ROW as your parameter. It works now.

Comment: which one is the `KEY` cloumn in there ?

Comment: Hi, I forgot to add unique key on the column, it now works :)

Comment: I am adding this in answer. Please accept and upvote. that would be favor from your side ;)

Comment: **WARNING**: This has some severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) because user data is used inside the query. Whenever possible use **prepared statements**. These are quite straightforward to do in [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) where any user-supplied data is specified with a `?` or `:name` indicator that’s later populated using `bind_param` or `execute` depending on which one you’re using.
**NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or any user data directly in your query.

Comment: Major SQL injection vulnerabilities are likely in this code. Use parameterized queries.

Comment: Hi, I never put $_POST or $_GET directly to the SQL query, I always use "REAL_ESCAPE_STRING" if it is really necessary as the parameter. Is it works?

Answer (score 2):

If it is inserting duplicate data, most likely, none of the columns you are inserting have the `UNIQUE`or `PRIMARY KEY` modifier.

Answer (score 0):

Please specify the `KEY` `column` and it should work